# Filling UK support form

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

Is it possible or compulsory to submit my bank accounts details after using a sponsor for my trip to UK and the sponsor will submit all his documents?

Comment: If you do not submit your bank statements your visa will be 100% refused. See the linked Q&A above for further details.

Comment: If your personal circumstances are such that you would be expected to have a bank account, for example you are employed/self-employed, then you will be refused if you don’t provide statements. If you don’t have a bank account, state that in your covering letter and explain why not (you may still be refused - see the linked question).